# change column types during merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I read a df like this:

```
chunksize = 10000000
df = pd.read_sql_table(src_tablename, engine, "core", 
                       chunksize=chunksize)

proposals = pd.read_sql_table("proposals", 
                       engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True),
                       "zone_03_refined", columns=columns)

for chunk in df:
    chunk = chunk.merge(proposals, left_on=["col1"], right_on=["col2"],
                    how='left')
```

However, the `merge`gives me an error because the types of `col1` and `col2` are apparently different.

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

I tried this in the loop:

```
    chunk["col1"] = chunk["col1"].astype(int)
    proposals["col2"] = proposals["col2"].astype(int)
```

but I get an error on the second line:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

how can I change the types during the merge itself?

Comment: so you already have the solution? convert the column and then do the merge?

Comment: I don't have the sol. Astype doesn't work probably because the ```df```is a generator. See how i am reading it. Edited the qs @oskros

Comment: This might be because you have some nan, none, NaN in your data. Could you try a df = df.fillna('') then try doing df = df['column'].astype(int)

Comment: I don't want to replace NaNs with empty strings. Any other way? @ArchAngelPwn

Comment: I mean you can change it to anything you want, If you wanted to do df = df.fillna('Whatever text you want') works as well.

Comment: yes but I want them to remain nans/null values @ArchAngelPwn (if any)

Comment: So what I would do in this situation would be to change the value to something that couldn't exist somewhere else like df = df.fillna('-1') (or something else that wouldn't exist in the dataset anywhere naturally) then do your merge, then once the merge is complete do a df = df.apply(lambda x : x.replace('-1', np.nan))